# Error call method of model from other Controller Rails 4 undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4

Using Rails 4.0

I am a litle problem i think, i create a model Word.rb, and this model have a method to create new Word, my proble is when i try acess this method using `Word.saveWord(params..)` this return a undefined method, i show the files to best explain:

**Word.rb**

```
  class Word < ActiveRecord::Base

  def saveWord(*args)
    args.each do |term|
       @term = Word.new(:name => term,:score => 0)
       @term.save
    end
  end


  before_save :check_repeated


  def check_repeated
    @term = Word.find_by_name(self.name)
    @term.score += 1 if @term.present?
  end
```

I dont know if can use this method from other controller because im try using from my **recipes_controller.rb**:

```
def search 
      @recipes = Recipe.search(params[:term],params[:term_1],params[:term_2]) if request.get?

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @recipes,:only => [:id,:name,:rcp_img_file_name,:time] }
      format.xml { render :xml => @recipes }
       # render :xml => @recipes.to_xml(:include => :category)
       #render :xml => @recipes     
    end


      Word.saveWord(params[:term].to_s)


  end
```

and i give this error:

```
undefined method `saveWord' for #<Class:0x007feb3f09bac8>
.. 


      Word.saveWord(params[:term].to_s)


  end
```

Please someone have a sugestion to me ? thanks much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `saveWord` is an instance method but you're calling it as a `class` method.  Since you're instantiating a new `Word` in your `saveWord` method, I assume you'd want to keep it a class method.  In such case update `saveWord` method to be instance method as follows:

```
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base    
  def self.saveWord(*args)
    args.each do |term|
      @term = Word.new(:name => term,:score => 0)
      @term.save
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You implemented `saveWord` as instance method, but you try to call it as class method. 
You probably need to reimplement this as class method:

```
def self.save_word(*args)
  args.each do |term|
    @term = Word.new(:name => term,:score => 0)
    @term.save
  end
end
```

I also changed this method's name, so now it follows Ruby naming convention.